# With MICE package, how to create a list of models from a list of variables to test with glm

Tags: r, loops, imputation, r-mice

I want to do t-test（or chi^2 test） to estimate the difference of variables between `grou=0` and `grou=1`. All variables in the dataset are imputed by MICE.  Variables include `AGE`,`SCORE`,`GENDER`, `HEART`, etc.; `AGE` and `SCORE` are  continuous variables, and `GENDER` and `HEART` are categorical variables.

If the t-test is done for only one variable at a time, I know the code is：

```
library(MICE)
data_im<-mice(data, m=5,seed=6666)
summary(pool(with(data_im,glm(AGE~grou))))
```

The output `p-value` is also the `p-value` of the t-test.

However, there are too many variables I need to evaluate，thus I would like to write a for loop or create a function to  output the summary test results of multiple variable at once.

I have tried to write:

```
vars <- c("AGE","SCORE","GENDER","HEART")
afterMICE <- c()
for(i in 1:4){
  pool_fitMICE <- pool(with(data_im,glm(substitute(y ~ grou,list(y=as.name(vars[i]))))))
}

**Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'AGE' not found**

afterMICE <- rbind(afterMICE,C(vars[i],coef(summary(pool_fitMICE))[2,c(1,2,4)]))
```

I know the reason for the error is that `data_im` is not a regular dataframe structure.

How to modify the code to achieve batch output of summary results from different variables？

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Edit**:
`mice()` is a function to do multivariate imputation for missing data. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.15.0/topics/mice

Take the `data("nhanes2")`  for example and we can see the structure of `data_im`.

```
library(MICE)
data("nhanes2")
vars=c("bmi","chl","age","hyp")
catvars=c("age","hyp")
data_im=mice(nhanes2,m=5,seed=6666)
pool.fits <- pool(with(data_im, glm(age~hyp)))
```

But we need to batch pool the results of `pool(with(data_im, glm(vars~hyp)))` (Variables in `vars` take turns being a dependent variable in `glm()`, with `hyp` as the independent variable. )

Comment: for dynamic generation of formulas for models, you may look into `reformulate`. `reformulate` may save you from the `paste`/`substitute`/`as.name` hell

Comment: It is also o bit weird that you are defining an `afterMICE` object before the for loop, but not using it enywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to mess around with `eval` and `substitute` in this situation. You can create the formula normally (using `as.formula` for example) and when the formula is evaluated inside `with` it will automatically find the variables in the imputed data.

```r
library(mice)
set.seed(123)
vars <- c("age", "bmi", "chl")
imps <- mice(nhanes, printFlag = FALSE)
mods <- list()
for(i in seq_along(vars)) {
  mods[[i]] <- pool(with(imps, 
                         glm(as.formula(paste0(vars[[i]], "~ hyp")))))
}
names(mods) <- vars
lapply(mods, summary)
#> $age
#>          term  estimate std.error statistic       df   p.value
#> 1 (Intercept) 0.5216374 0.4873196  1.070422 17.71793 0.2987954
#> 2         hyp 1.0163241 0.3744249  2.714360 19.13894 0.0136971
#> 
#> $bmi
#>          term   estimate std.error   statistic       df      p.value
#> 1 (Intercept) 27.0037636  2.882558  9.36798555 16.45801 5.297937e-08
#> 2         hyp -0.1502389  2.191507 -0.06855506 18.35948 9.460849e-01
#> 
#> $chl
#>          term  estimate std.error statistic       df      p.value
#> 1 (Intercept) 157.88698  24.65957  6.402665 20.91373 2.445428e-06
#> 2         hyp  29.06627  19.62684  1.480945 19.90150 1.542804e-01
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Edit: Putting output into a data.frame.

```r
out <- data.frame(var = vars,
                  coef_int = 0,
                  coef_hyp = 0)
for(i in seq_along(vars)) {
  out[i, 2:3] <- mods[[i]]$pooled$estimate
}
out
#>   var    coef_int   coef_hyp
#> 1 age   0.5216374  1.0163241
#> 2 bmi  27.0037636 -0.1502389
#> 3 chl 157.8869758 29.0662740
```

Comment: Thank you , this is the main answer I was looking for. I also would like to know how to extract a data frame with the  `vars` as lines and `coef` from `summary` as columns from the last list we obtained above?

Comment: @tumidou I'm not sure this is what you mean, but I added some code that puts the `estimate`s from each model into a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic generation of formulas for models, you may look into `reformulate`. `reformulate` may save you from the `paste`/`substitute`/`as.name` hell. I believe we do not need `with()`too. It may generate some environment confusion.

```
vars <- c("AGE","SCORE","GENDER","HEART")

list_of_formulas <- lapply(vars, \(x) reformulate(termlabels = 'grou', response = x))
```

see the created list of formulas:

```
[[1]]
AGE ~ grou
<environment: 0x557191bff8b8>

[[2]]
SCORE ~ grou
<environment: 0x557191c07b58>

[[3]]
GENDER ~ grou
<environment: 0x557191cb30f8>

[[4]]
HEART ~ grou
<environment: 0x557191ccad40>
```

Then use this list in your for loop.

```
pool_fitMICE <- list()
for(i in 1:4){
  pool_fitMICE[[i]] <- pool(glm(formula = list_of_formulas[[i]], data = data_im))
}
```

We can also obviate the need to initiate the output list or using a for loop if we use a loop-function:

```
lapply(list_of_formulas, \(x) pool(glm(formula = x, data = data_im))
```

Comment: Error reported: `Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘"mids"’ to a data.frame`  ;I think the problem is still in the data structure of `data_im`, because after MICE , it is no longer a classic dataframe.

Comment: i dont know MICE that much. Can you share at lesat a subset of `data_im`? maybe you can use `dput(head(data_im))`, or `dput(data_im[1:4])`

Comment: Hi~ I posted the structure of `data_im` in Edit.

Comment: please do not share images of data. Share the actual code for your data so we can work on it. Use dput

Comment: After dput(data_im[2:4])，it cannot even be displayed in one page……and the data is very redundant.

Comment: Hi~I take the `data("nhanes2")` for example in Edits,  then we could know the structure of `data_im` clearly.