# How to use CreateTableOne() in with() after mice to get a pooled results?

Tags: r, dataframe, imputation, r-mice

I would like to use `CreateTableOne()` to calculate `SMD(standardized mean difference)` of variables between two groups(`grou=0` and `grou=1`) after Mice imputed. But I found that `CreateTableOne()` could not be nested inside `with()`.

```
library(tableone)
library(MICE)
data("nhanes2")
vars=c("bmi","chl","age","hyp")
catvars=c("age","hyp")
data_im=mice(nhanes2,m=5,seed=6666)
pool(with(data_im,CreateTableOne(vars = vars, factorVars= catvars,strata = "hyp", test =TRUE)))

# **Error in ModuleStopIfNotDataFrame(data) : 
#   argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

How to calculate SMD of imputed dataset through pool()?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick      Ok, I take the ```data("nhanes2")``` for example in Edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the tables with

```
with(data_im, CreateTableOne(
  vars = vars, 
  data=as.data.frame(mget(ls())), 
  factorVars=catvars,strata = "hyp", test =TRUE))
```

We use `mget()` to grab all the variables in the environment and turn them into a data.frame.

This will return a list of TableOne objects. But there's no method to `pool` such objects so it's not clear how you want to calculate SMD. There are no groups in this example. If you want advice on how to combine statistical values from multiple imputations, you should ask for statistical advice at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: OK，thanks so much. Could you also help me with this question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548093/with-mice-package-how-to-create-a-list-of-models-from-a-list-of-variables-to-te, it seems to be the same type of this one.